# How to include null list into xml response with JAXB

Tags: soap, jaxb, cxf

I have a CXF SOAP service with JAXB marshaller and this is the autogenerated stub class from the wsdl2java utility:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ResultOperation", propOrder = {
    "result",
    "ElementList"
})
public class ResultOperation {
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected Result result;
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<ElementList> elementList;
// getters, setters...
}
```

When elementList is null, I expect to see following XML:

```
<soap:Envelope>
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:getOperationResponse>
         <ns2:return>
            <ns4:result>
            ...data...
            </ns4:result>
            <ns4:elementList xsi:nil="true"/>
         </ns2:return>
      </ns2:getOperationResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But I get this instead:

```
<soap:Envelope>
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:getOperationResponse>
         <ns2:return>
            <ns4:result>
            ...data...
            </ns4:result>
         </ns2:return>
      </ns2:getOperationResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there a proper way to include null collection into the response?

I know that `@XmlElementWrapper(nillable = true)` annotation would work, but it wraps collection with another tag when it's not null which I don't need.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround with adding null element to the elementList:
`resultOperation.getElementList.add(null);`

It returns null element in the XML as I expect:

```
<soap:Envelope>
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:getOperationResponse>
         <ns2:return>
            <ns4:result>
            ...data...
            </ns4:result>
            <ns4:elementList xsi:nil="true"/>
         </ns2:return>
      </ns2:getOperationResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```